# How to differentiate left/right shift, ctrl, alt and enter keys in JavaFX?

Tags: java, keyboard, javafx, javafx-8, keyboard-events

How can a JavaFX 8 controller tell whether a <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is located on the left or right part of the keyboard?

The `getKeyLocation()` method in `java.awt.event.KeyEvent` doesn't exist for the `javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent` class unfortunately.

I also tried to check the `event.location` in a Javascript by intercepting `window.onkeydown`, but unlike V8 or other JS engines, it seems the Nashorn library doesn't discriminate them and returns `DOM_KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD` no matter where the key is located.

Since the overall key capture seems pretty much broken (inconsistencies in `KeyEvent::getCode`/`keyText` methods), I'm starting to think an external library will be necessary. Is there a solution in the JavaFX (or Java) library, and if not, a lightweight library that could offer the same functionality on different platforms (Windows, Linux and Mac OS)?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Tried with JavaFX + awt component (see [suggestion below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25596675/183575)), but wouldn't work as it seems JavaFX provides and translates the events - incorrectly.

Tried with [JNativeHook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/) (they [recently moved](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook)), it *almost* qualifies as a work-around but fails to recognize some keys, has imprecise timing and is a bit awkward to implement, especially since I can't compile the native code for all the platforms. The licencing terms are also a bit confused (GPL for the stable version, which isn't an option in my case, perhaps moving to LGPL...).

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, there's currently no API for determining which physical key was pressed in JavaFX. It's hard to see how a third party library could implement this, as it would have to intercept the low-level implementation of JavaFX in a way that is not really accessible to such code.

If this is important to you, I'd recommend filing a feature request at https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/

Comment: In the mean time I found JNativeHook, and I'm desperate enough to give it a try. Thanks for the link, I should probably report the erratic and incomplete behaviour of key event system.

Comment: Please do file a bug report.  I have had good responses from the JavaFX team on bug reports and feature requests.

Comment: I did. Also noticed they didn't implement any timestamp (getWhen) on the event, which is pretty much a no-go for that framework. I'm afraid I'll have to switch to .NET and wait until JavaFX is mature (and hopefully, Java 8 too) until thinking about multiple platform support :(

Comment: Can you post a link to the jira request?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just using [java.awt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html) because it would work perfectly for what you need. It is pretty light-weight and, more importantly, it provides support for Windows, Linux, and Mac OS. You can find a simple example [here](http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game4.html).

I think the thing that will be the most helpful is the fact that it does provide differentiation between right and left with `KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT` or `KEY_LOCATION_LEFT` as mentioned in the docs found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)

For example: `getKeyCode` might return `VK_SHIFT` and then `getKeyLocation` might return `KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT` which would obviously indicate that the right shift key was pressed at which point you could execute whatever you need to.

Good luck!

Comment: That was one idea, though the behaviour in JavaFX doesn't support getKeyLocation, the return values are always `KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN`. They really did a good job with Java 8 ;) Besides, I wasn't really keen on mixing JavaFX with Awt - would have as a work-around if it worked, but it's apparently not the case.